# simultaneous trigonometric equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Consider the pair of simultaneous equations

$p_5\cos(2\omega\tau)+p_4\omega\sin(2\omega\tau) = p_1\omega^2-p_3-p_6\cos(3\omega\tau) $, 
$p_4\omega\cos(2\omega\tau)-p_5\sin(2\omega\tau) = \omega^3-p_2\omega+p_6\sin(3\omega\tau)$.

Forget about all the other parameters/variables in the equations. All I want is to find a closed form expression for $\tau$. Thanks for your help and ideas!

Comment: Might not be possible. The problem is equivalent to a closed form expression for $\cos(\omega\tau)$. Roughly speaking, the first equation is cubic, the second cubic too. Plus the identity $c^2+s^2=1$ a quadratic, you should theoretically have a degree $3\times 3\times 2=18$ polynomial (Bezout theorem). The actual degree might be much lower, but unlikely lower than $5$. You won't have a closed form solution in this case.